# Schatten p norm p>1

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

The Schatten p norm is differentiable away from the origin for p> 1.   Does a stronger condition of Lipschitz continuity of the gradient also hold?

Comment: I do not agree that the Schatten $p$-norm is differentiable. In particular, it is not so at the origin. So this suggests to me that it does not have a Lipschitz continuous derivative outside of the origin, either.

Comment: [This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0362) purports to prove the differentiability of the Schatten norm *away from zero*. That's a critical qualification for the purposes of your question.

Comment: Yes, I'll add a qualification for away from zero.

Comment: But I think that basically answers the question. It can't be Lipschitz continuous because the gradient gets *larger* close to the origin.

Comment: Yes.  Does taking the $p^{th}$ power of the norm smooth it out?

Comment: Yes, the $p$th power can be differentiated $\lfloor p \rfloor$ times, as the paper shows. But my suspicion is that it will not be Lipschitz continuous for $p>2$.

Comment: Michael, what I was looking for was a "smoother" heuristic for low rank matrix completion than the nuclear norm.   I thought a Schatten $p$-norm to the $p^{th}$ power (1<$p$, $p$ close to 1) would be a good candidate, but it seems it may not be Lipschitz differentiable.   Are there any  convex Lipschitz differentiable penalties that promote approximate low rank properties for matrix completion?

Comment: I do not believe so. If you're trying to build a gradient method anyway, why not just use a proximal gradient method and use the nuclear norm to build the prox function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21352/discussion-between-digital-gal-and-michael-grant).

Answer (score 1):

Since any norm is homogeneous of degree 1, its gradient is homogeneous of degree 0 where it exists. Therefore this gradient cannot be Lipschitz at the origin.

However, the $p$th power of the norm certainly has an analytic gradient if $p = 2$, since that is just the Frobenius norm. In general, $A \mapsto \|A\|_p$ has a gradient that is homogeneous of degree $p-1$. This should imply that the gradient of this map is locally  Lipschitz iff $p \ge 1$. It cannot be globally Lipschitz if $p > 2$.

Comment: I'm so glad that you had the homogeneity argument in hand. I was working on a proof from first principles but that's unnecessary. What it does say, however, is that I was incorrect to say that the gradient gets "larger" closer to the origin. But the local Lipschitz constant does get larger: let $X,Y$ be two distinct points where a gradient exists. Then for $t>0$
$$\frac{\| \nabla f(tX)-\nabla f(tY) \|_*}{\|tX-tY\|} = \frac{\| \nabla f(X)-\nabla f(Y) \|_*}{\|tX-tY\|} = t^{-1} \frac{\|\nabla f(X)-\nabla f(Y)\|_*}{\|X-Y\|}$$so as $t\rightarrow 0$, the ratio approaches $+\infty$.

Comment: That's because the Lipschitz constant of the gradient is like the second derivative which is homogeneous of degree $-1$ :)